# Can ads be removed from personal ucoz site using CSS or HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ads

Ucoz runs ads on all free sites whose owners opt not to pay money just to have these ads removed. Right now, there are two types of ads and I wonder if I can remove them from my site by the means of CSS or HTML. Please, advise.

The first one manifests itself as a top banner, it's a div that can be identified by `class="ads-top-banner"`.

The second one is a script that launches a pop-up once a visitor enters site and clicks anywhere. One of its tags is `data-cfasync="false"`

Thanks for any help. You can take this site as an example: [sid.at.ua](http://sid.at.ua)

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to put all the content of your site into a div with some id and remove everything except this div on a page load. But I'm pretty sure it is illegal.

Comment: A bit of an overshoot. Seems that it would be easier to just remove two elements instead. I know it can be done via certain scripts as I was able to remove ucoz ads in the past using instructions found in the web, but with implementations of new ads they stopped working and I'm not savvy enough to tailor the scripts to these new ads.

Comment: Yup, now you can see the main advantage of my method. Even if ucoz changes ads, they will not display.

Comment: So I tried sticking the site into a div with a class **diffx**. I then added this to css: **:not(.diffx) {display:none}**. The site wouldn't load after that.